# How to concatenate a string line in Select clause in DB connection of VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have a simple DB query that selects data from a worksheet and pass it to 2 different worksheets over 2 query stages. I believe it can be simpler, but I'm trying to embed (VField) inside the select clause to avoid repeating it again to add the extra 2 fields.

Here's the code I have to embed the VField in the select clause.

```
 Option Explicit
Sub Demmo()
'Declare Variables
Dim con, Rs As Object, sql As String
Dim VField As String
On Error GoTo errClose
'Connection string
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With con
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
       End With
'Select clause and VField = nothing to feed summary worksheet
sql = "SELECT T1.[ID],T1.[ID Name], " & _
      VField & _
      "T1.[country],T1.[Unit reference] " & _
      ",sum(T1.[Total]) as [Total] " & _
      "FROM [Data$] T1 " & _
      "WHERE T1.[ID Name] = 'XX' " & _
      "GROUP BY T1.[ID],T1.[ID Name], " & _
      VField & _
      "T1.[country],T1.[Unit reference]"
'set recordset to execute connection string
         Set PRs = PConn.Execute(sql)
'Pass the data from recordset to summary sheet
Sheets("Summary").Cells(1, 2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
'reference VField to Inv.Number and Inv.Date fields
    VField = "T1.[Inv Number],T1.[Inv Date], "
'Re-run select clause (sql) to feed Detilas worksheet
         sql = sql ' still read VField as nothing and i need sql to read it as declared 
         Set PRs = PConn.Execute(sql)
'Pass the data from recordset to Details sheet
Sheets("Details").Cells(1, 2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
'close record set, connection and free memory
        Rs.Close
       con.Close
     Set Rs = Nothing
     Set con = Nothing
 End
'close recordset on error
errClose:
        If Not (Rs Is Nothing) Then
        If (Rs.State And 1) = 1 Then Rs.Close
        Set Rs = Nothing
           End If
 MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")  " & Err.Source
End Sub
```

Comment: Once you've concatenated VField into your SQL string, you can't later change the value of VField and have your SQL auto-update to match.  Variables in VBA don't work that way.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for that, is there any better way to reach the same result without repeating the select clause again to add 2 extra fields in between?

Comment: See my suggestion below. FYI your code uses `PRs` and `Rs`....

Comment: No, It is meant to be Rs as recordset PRs is a typo error. let me give that function a go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a function:

```
Function GetSql(VField As String) As String
    GetSql = "SELECT T1.[ID],T1.[ID Name], " & _
       VField & _
      "T1.[country],T1.[Unit reference] " & _
      ",sum(T1.[Total]) as [Total] " & _
      "FROM [Data$] T1 " & _
      "WHERE T1.[ID Name] = 'XX' " & _
      "GROUP BY T1.[ID],T1.[ID Name], " & _
      VField & _
      "T1.[country],T1.[Unit reference]"
End Function
```

Then you can call (eg):

`Set PRs = PConn.Execute(GetSql(""))`

or

`Set PRs = PConn.Execute(GetSql("T1.[Inv Number],T1.[Inv Date], "))`